# mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou enfrentando um erro no meu código, quando executo o comportamento de servidor do DW c6, quando o passo de `mysql_` para `mysqli_`, nisso obtenho um erro na função executado na linha 10.

O erro é:

> Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\LojaVirtualDin\footer.php on line 10

Essa é linha do código:

```
$theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue);

Esse é o código:

<?php require_once('Connections/config.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['login'];
  $password=$_POST['senha'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "nivel";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "admin/painel.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "admin/index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysqli_select_db($config,$database_config);

  $LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT usuario, senha, nivel FROM lp_users WHERE usuario=%s AND senha=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysqli_query($config, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysqli_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'nivel');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    } 
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender esse erro?

Comment: Não use esse código O.o. quando as funções mysqli são utilizadas o primeiro argumento é sempre a conexão, é isso que diz o erro.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta veja se está correta, se tiver algum erro deixe ele no comentário. Coloca o link da onde você achou esse código

Comment: Marque um resposta como aceita, veja mais detalhes em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 4):

Quando as funções mysqli são utilizadas o primeiro argumento é sempre a conexão, é isso que diz o erro. A [documentaçã](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)o mostra como deve ser a chamada:

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Troque as ocorrencias de:

```
 $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue);
```

Por:

```
 $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($config, $theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($config, $theValue);
```

Prefira utilizar prepares statements ao utilizar esse código generico, lembre de mudar `mysql_result()` no seu código.

Comment: Sim já fiz essa modificação, mas o erro persiste,não sei a que fazer.

Comment: @saulo, vc alterou duas vezes?

Comment: sim alterei, o que acontece, quando faço a chamada variável ela não é reconhecida dentro do parentese onde vai a variável $config

Comment: Isso é porque você só faz o require da configuração depois de usar o link da conexão. Tem de fazer o require antes.

Comment: Sim, querido, agradeço muito a você, pelo seu carinho, mas sou um iniciante estou todo confuso, e reconheço que não sei como proceder, mas muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Obrigado.

Comment: Resolvido.Fiz a chamada do 'include' abaixo da linha:function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{, na lnha do erro: mysqli_real_escape_string($config, $theValue), fiz a chamada do $link. Deu tudo certo .Muito obrigado pela ajuda.Ok!

Comment: Legal @saulo :D, tem uns materias na [wiki do php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) se quier ver, tem algumas dicas bem uteis.

Comment: Ta legal que Cristo Jesus te abençoe.

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)  necessita de 2 parâmetros para executar:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link ,  $escapestr );
```

ao contrário da [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) que só necessitava de 1 parâmetro:

```
mysql_real_escape_string ( $escapestr );
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro acontece pois a função `mysqli_real_escape_string` espera receber 2 parâmetros no modo procedural.

`string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

E apenas 1 parâmetro no modo orientado.

`string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr )`

[Documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)