# Erro fatal gerado em código PHP msql. Como atualizar o código para mysqli e PHP 7 e corrig o erro?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sou iniciante em PHP, estou fazendo um projeto imobiliário em PHP de um curso que eu comprei, e apareceu um problema na parte de configuração do painel de login do projeto. O problema é que quando eu autentico os campos de login e senha acusa o seguinte erro fatal do xdebug:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\imobiliaria\admin\index.php on line 52
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\imobiliaria\admin\index.php on line 52

O curso é meio antigo, a versão do PHP do curso é abaixo da versão 5 e ele ainda utiliza métodos e funções da conexão de banco de dados descontinuado mysql. Estou desenvolvendo o projeto com o wamp na versão PHP 7 e com a ide visual studio code, e nesta versão do wamp se utiliza apenas as conexões do padrão mysqli e PDO. No curso o instrutor utiliza um recurso do menu do dreamweaver que gera o código de conexão automaticamente no formato procedural. O problema é que o código gerado utiliza métodos descontinuados da conexão mysql e eu já tentei de tudo para corrigir o problema de conexão, já tentei substituir os métodos descontinuados pelos do mysqli porém vai aparecendo mais mensagens de erro. Gostaria de saber qual o jeito correto de atualizar o código para o mysqli e como usar um código melhor e mais simples do que o gerado pelo dreanweaver e feito na unha. Segue abaixo o código da da pagina de configuração de conexão e a pagina index com o código do dreamweaver. Obrigado, fico no aguardo.

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_painel_config = "localhost";
$database_painel_config = "imobi";
$username_painel_config = "root";
$password_painel_config = "";
$painel_config = mysqli_connect($hostname_painel_config,
 $username_painel_config, $password_painel_config) 
 or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

página:

```
<?php require_once('C:\wamp64\www\imobiliaria\connections\painel_config.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['senha'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "usuarioNivel";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "painel.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "restrito.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_painel_config, $painel_config);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT email, senha, usuarioNivel FROM freitas_clientes WHERE email=%s AND senha=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $painel_config) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'usuarioNivel');

  if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Faça seu Login - Freitas Imóveis</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="login">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
   <form name="login_painel" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST">
    <label><span>E-mail: </span><input type="text" name="email" /></label>
    <label><span>Senha: </span><input type="password" name="senha" /></label>
    <p><a href="recover.php">[ Esqueci minha senha ]</a><p>
    <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Logar" class="btn" />
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` passe como quarto argumento o nome do banco de dados. Tem mais erros ai, sugiro dar uma lida nos links a direita.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e continua dando a mesma mensagem de erro. Eu também tentei realizar o procedimento de um problema com o código semelhante ao meu deste usuário do stack overlfow http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88119/mysqli-escape-string-expects-exactly-2-parameters-1-given , nele o usuario diz que resolveu o problema   fazendo  a chamada do 'include' abaixo da linha:function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") {, na lnha do erro: mysqli_real_escape_string($config, $theValue),ele fez a chamada do $link. mas eu não sei como fazer a chamada

Comment: Ao migrar um código que utiliza as funções `MySQL` (obsoletas) para o `MySQLi` uma dica é, em quase todas as funções o primeiro argumento a ser passado é a conexão, [nesse link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) tem a lista de funções e quais argumentos devem ser passados. Detalhe não existe nenhuma função correspondente para `mysql_result()` no MySQL**i**.